# Is a basis vector always unit-length in a wave function?

Tags: wavefunction, hilbert-space, vectors, linear-algebra, normalization

I'm currently studying wave functions and I came across an assertion, that

$$\psi(x) = \left<x \middle| \psi \right>$$

is a projection of $\psi$ onto $x$. The vector projection being defined as

$$proj_x \psi = \frac{x \cdot \psi}{||x||} \frac{x}{||x||},$$

I don't see, how a wave-function, being just the scalar product, could be a projection, unless $x$ is always a unit-length vector.

Is it true? And if $x$ has always unit length, could you, please, explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ket $|x\rangle$ is a little bit more complicated than that. Consider one Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and one orthonormal basis $e_i\in \mathcal{H}$.

If $\{e_i : i \in I\}$ is an orthonormal basis then two different elements are orthogonal and each one has unit length. In other words:

$$\langle e_i,e_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}.$$

So far so good. The issue is that the so-called "generalized basis" of "generalized eigenkets" of the unbounded operator $X$, namely $|x\rangle$, is normalized according to:

$$\langle x|x'\rangle=\delta(x-x').$$

So you see that while in the discrete case $\langle e_i, e_i\rangle = 1$ and it makes sense, in the generalized case $\langle x | x\rangle = \delta(0)$ which doesn't make sense at all. The very norm of $|x\rangle$ is ill-defined.

The fact is that while this is usually ignored in Quantum Mechanics, if you have one unbounded operator $X : \mathcal{D}(X)\to \mathcal{H}$ acting on its domain inside $\mathcal{H}$, while it makes sense to talk about the spectrum $\sigma(X)$ of the operator, there is not a set of basis vectors $|x\rangle\in \mathcal{H}$ such that $X|x\rangle = x | x\rangle$. There is however a quite different treatment with the so-called Gel'fand triplets also known as Rigged Hilbert Spaces, which allow us to realize $|x\rangle$ as actual elements of a larger space.

So these kets $|x\rangle$ do not behave in the exact same manner as the $e_i$ I quoted above. They are not even elements of $\mathcal{H}$.

Despite all this, the normalization works in the sense of the spectral decomposition. Actually with this normalization

$$\int \langle x|\psi\rangle |x\rangle dx = |\psi\rangle$$

in the same way that

$$\sum \langle e_i, \psi\rangle e_i = \psi$$

for normalized $\{e_i : i\in I\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$| x \rangle$ is normalized in a sense that one can use it in this identity operator (this formula is also called "Completeness relation"):

$$
\mathbb{1} = \int dx \; | x \rangle \langle x |
$$

Neither $| p \rangle$ nor $| x \rangle$ are normalizable in normal sense of wavefunctions since $\langle x | x' \rangle = \delta(x - x')$. Thus that projection formula won't work for them. However applying that identity to a general wavefunction:

$$
| \psi \rangle = \int dx \; | x \rangle \langle x| \psi \rangle =
  \int dx \; \psi(x) | x \rangle
$$

Will give you a decomposition of the wavefunction in $|x \rangle$ basis.